# PicoCLI : Options order in Usage section

Tags: picocli

I have set sortOptions to false for command but still, I am seeing command's options in sorted order in the Usage section.
I want to see them in their declaration order.

**Sample code**

```
@Command(name = "application", subcommands = { AddSubCommand.class })
public class Sample implements Runnable {
    @Spec CommandSpec spec;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        throw new ParameterException(spec.commandLine(), "Specify a subcommand");
    }

    public static void main(String... args) {
        new CommandLine(new Sample()).execute("add", "-h");
    }
}

@Command(name = "add", sortOptions = false)
class AddSubCommand implements Runnable {
    @Option(names = { "-h" }, usageHelp = true, hidden = true)
    boolean helpFlag;

    @Option(names = { "-i" }, required = true, description = "id")
    int id;

    @Option(names = { "-t" }, required = true, description = "type")
    String type;

    @Option(names = { "-c" }, required = true, description = "config")
    String config;

    public void run() {
        // logic
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
Usage: application add -c=<config> -i=<id> -t=<type>
  -i=<id>        id
  -t=<type>      type
  -c=<config>    configuration
```

**Expectation**

```
Usage: application add  -i=<id> -c=<config> -t=<type>
  -i=<id>        id
  -t=<type>      type
  -c=<config>    configuration
```

Answer (score 2):

You are correct that options are sorted in the synopsis line, regardless of whether `sortOptions = false` is specified. (The `sortOptions` annotation attribute only affects the order of the *options list* section of the usage help message, not the synopsis.)

It is possible to customize the synopsis, but not with the annotations API; you will need to use the programmatic API.

Change the `Sample` class `main` method to the following:

```java
public static void main(String... args) {
    new CommandLine(new Sample())
            .setHelpFactory(new UnsortedSynopsisHelpFactory())
            .execute("add", "-h");
}
```

And add the following `UnsortedSynopsisHelpFactory` class:

```java
class UnsortedSynopsisHelpFactory implements CommandLine.IHelpFactory {

    @Override
    public CommandLine.Help create(CommandSpec commandSpec, ColorScheme colorScheme) {
        return new CommandLine.Help(commandSpec, colorScheme) {
            @Override
            protected Ansi.Text createDetailedSynopsisOptionsText(
                    Collection<ArgSpec> done,
                    Comparator<OptionSpec> optionSort,
                    boolean clusterBooleanOptions) {

                return super.createDetailedSynopsisOptionsText(
                        done, 
                        null,  // do not sort options in synopsis
                        clusterBooleanOptions);
            }
        };
    }
}
```

This will give the following output:

```
Usage: application add -i=<id> -t=<type> -c=<config>
  -i=<id>        id
  -t=<type>      type
  -c=<config>    config
```

Thanks for raising this! I added an example [Unsorted.java](https://github.com/remkop/picocli/blob/master/picocli-examples/src/main/java/picocli/examples/synopsis/Unsorted.java) to the `picocli-examples` module.